# Why is MD5 much faster on Intel x86 than PowerPC?

Tags: assembly, x86, md5, cpu-architecture, powerpc

I'm looking at the performance of MD5 (using it for back-up, I understand this is a somewhat out-dated crypto method) on Intel x86 and PowerPC (an IBM POWER7, specifically), and seemingly Power takes about twice the time to execute compared to x86.

The difference would be that there's an assembly version generated for x86 which the performance maybe tuned up already, I'm trying to see if there's a similar way to improve the performance on Power, but I'm not sure where to start looking and wondering if anyone would have an idea.

Just some more background info, the file I'm passing in is large(~2G), I haven't made any effort to parallelize it at all, it's all sequential.

Also, when i tried different ones(SHA1 for example, or other ones from the sha family), the performances are very close..so wondering if there's anything special about MD5

Comment: What is an "IBM Power Machine?"  Are you referring to the [Power PC?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC)  Have you accounted for factors like clock speed?

Comment: It'd hard to compare architectures unless you have optimized implementations for all of them. Even within an architecture performance can vary greatly. Newer CPUs can often do a lot more withing a single clock cycle than older CPUs. For example a modern Intel CPU should hash your 2GB file in 4 seconds using a single core if your IO can keep up.

Comment: yea it's a powerPC, power7 i believe

Comment: Are you sure the performance is not limited by I/O? What exactly are you measuring - the file hashing time, or the memory block hashing time? The latter could be quite different (and even then, note the possibility of paging).

Comment: "Optimizing Subroutines in Assembly Language" is for x86, but many of the concepts are portable http://www.slideshare.net/edersonsd/optimizing-assembly you may have better starting point results for different sections with different compilers too.

Comment: If you're able to break down the MD5 code you use into a short critical kernel, and provide the assembly for it on both architectures, maybe we'll be able to find possible explanations. Otherwise it's too broad a question. It may be self explanatory once you do that, in case it's using specialized ISA on x86.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know specifically about POWER7, but it seems that a number of POWER micro-architectures have a [minimum 2 cycle latency on many instructions](https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=185286&curpostid=185288).

MD5 performance is a [latency bound problem](https://github.com/animetosho/md5-optimisation#md5-performance-a-latency-problem), which means that CPUs with high latency instructions will suffer. A CPU with 2 cycle latency should roughly be in the ballpark of a 1 cycle latency CPU at half the clock rate.